# Arduino thinks I pressed a switch when I touch anything

Tags: arduino

So I have found something very strange and confusing, When I touch anything even my desk my arduino thinks I connected to the input of any pin I pick.

here is a video of what is happening

it even does it when connected directly to a battery

[here is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yf21TmoYBlE)

Comment: +1 for fancy question title

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Floating input is influenced by the charge on your body.  Put a 10k resistor on that input (the switch input, that is) to GND or VCC and that behavior should largely go away. You can also probably get away with enabling the internal pull up / down on the pin in software (the second argument to the `pinMode` function in Arduino-speak).